# How to print a specific key from a dictionary of dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict of dicts. I want to check if a given key is available in one of the internal dicts and if so, it will print `f "{key} took the book {value}"`. Else, it will print `"Sorry book not available."`.

Example of the data I have:

```
external_dict = {1: {"Larry" : "Harry Potter and the chamber of secrets"}, 2: {"Ronald" : "marvel 
iron man comic"}, 3: {"Bernald" : "Hardy boys adventure Peril at Granite Peak"}}
```

Comment: How would you specify which key you want?

Comment: That's not your dictionary, because that code won't run (you've defined it like a set, not a dictionary, but it contains dictionaries, which aren't hashable, so it'll raise an error).  What is *actually* your dictionary and what are you trying to do with it?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
def book_finder():
  lent_list = [{"Larry" : "Harry Potter and the chamber of secrets"}, {"Ronald" : "marvel iron man comic"}, {"Bernald" : "Hardy boys adventure Peril at Granite Peak"}]
  for dic in lent_list:
    for value in dic.values():
      print(value)
  book_name = input("Enter a book name to find ")
  
  value = ""
  for dic in lent_list:
    for key,value in dic.items():
      if book_name == value:
        value = (f"{key} took the book {value}")
        return value
    
  value = "Sorry book not available."
  return value


print(book_finder())
```

Comment: Actually, this is not what I wanted

Comment: @Gaurav I modified the whole code. You don't have to have dictionaries inside a dictionary so I added them inside a list.

Comment: Your code is partly correct and I deleted the unwanted code and added some code, so it runs correctly now. Thanks @PyotrVanNostrand.